# Netlogo: creating specific links between turtles with information from csv

Tags: csv, netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I'm working on a simulation of social behavior in an emergency situation, using anonymized data from an actual event. Below is the section of code I'm using to create the 'people' turtles.

```
to read-people-from-file [filename]
  let rows bf csv:from-file filename
  foreach rows
  [[row] ->
create-people 1
[
 set size .46
 setxy (item 0 row) (item 1 row)
 set age (item 2 row)
 set gender (item 3 row)
 set visited? (item 4 row)
 set group-number (item 6 row)
 set group-type (item 7 row)
 if group-number < 300 and ((person group-number) = (other group-number))) [create-links-with other person]
]
 ]
end
```

Everything works except for the group-number based links. I've tried a few different variations of it, with no luck except where I attempted `if group-number <300 [create-links-with other people` which worked creating links but was functionally useless. What I'm trying to do is set it so that every person who came together (who has the same group number) has a link with other group members. It's specifically less than 300 because numbers 300 and above are for people who came alone or other designations.

I could theoretically create the links by hand after the turtles are created, but that seems both like a waste of time (I have a dataset of over 400) and like something that makes the code significantly less applicable to other scenarios.

How do I make Netlogo create links between members of the same group, based on what's in the CSV?

Actually, the dream answer: how do I make Netlogo create different breeds of links (based on group-type) between members of the same group-number, based on what's in the CSV?

Edit:
In the end, I had to separate creating links from the initial agent setup.
This was what worked:

```
 to soclink ;;groups that came together have links based type of relationship
ask people [if group-number < 300 
 [
if group-type = 1 [ask other people with [group-number = [group-number] of myself] [create-coworker-with myself]]
if group-type = 2 [ask other people with [group-number = [group-number] of myself] [create-friend-with myself]]
if group-type = 3 [ask other people with [group-number = [group-number] of myself] [create-partner-with myself]]
if group-type = 4 [ask other people with [group-number = [group-number] of myself] [create-family-with myself]]
if group-type = 5 [ask other people with [group-number = [group-number] of myself] [create-multiple-with myself]]

  show count links]]
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first part, maybe this would work- once your people are created, with their numbers assigned to `group-number`:

```
to group-link
  ask people [
    let my-group other people with [ group-number = [ group-number] of myself ]
    create-links-with my-group
  ]  
end
```

For the dream answer- it might depend on how many breeds of links you need. As far as I know, link breeds must be predefined- you could not programatically generate links as needed for different groups (although I am no expert- there may be a way). If you have your link breeds already defined, for example:

```
undirected-link-breed [ link-as link-a ]
undirected-link-breed [ link-bs link-b ]
```

Pretend now that your `group-type` is either "a" or "b", and you can do something like

```
to specific-link-breeds
  ask people [
    let my-group other people with [ group-number = [ group-number] of myself ]
    if group-type = "a" [
      create-link-as-with my-group
    ]
    if group-type = "b" [
      create-link-bs-with my-group
    ]
  ]
  ask link-as [ 
    set color red
  ]
  ask link-bs [
    set color blue
  ] 
end
```

**Edit:** Changed `turtles` to `people` as it should be- thanks Mattsap.

Comment: I also believe you need to pre-define your link breeds. However, it would be  straightforward to simply create an attribute of the links that contained group-type.

Comment: One improvement to not have so many if statements would be to create a table where the key is the group-type and the value would be the function create-link-xs-with where xs is replaced by each link-breed.  FYI, for beginner netlogoer's, if you have a more specific breed, use that (e.g. people) instead of the general turtle breed which calls all turtles---which would be bad if you have multiple breeds.

Comment: Thanks to you both- I agree. @mattsap- good catch, that was an oversight, I have edited to fix.